# Integration with parameters with maple

Tags: maple

I would like to compute (formally) some integrals which are just rational fraction and  which depends on 3 parameter. It works if I set two parameter to trivial value, else i must stop the computation after 5 min. Does anyone can help me to make it works?

Here is my worksheet:

```
restart;
omega(x,y):= 1/(1+x^(2)+y^(2))*<2*x,2*y,x^(2)+y^(2)-1>:

Omega(x,y, a,b, l):= simplify(omega(evalc(Re((l*(x+I*y)+a+Ib)/(1-(a-I*b)*(x+I*y))) ),evalc(`&Im;`((l*(x+I*y)+a+I*b)/(1-(a-I*b)*(x+I*y)))) )):
assume(0 < l);
simplify(int(int(Omega(x, y, a, b, l)[1]*(diff(Omega(x, y, a, b, l)[1], x)), x = -infinity .. infinity), y = -infinity .. infinity));

Warning,  computation interrupted
simplify(int(int(Omega(x, y, 0, 1, l)[3]*(diff(Omega(x, y, 0, 1, l)[1], x)), x = -infinity .. infinity), y = -infinity .. infinity));
Warning,  computation interrupted
simplify(int(int(Omega(x, y, 0, 0, l)[3]*(diff(Omega(x, y, 0, 0, l)[1], x)), x = -infinity .. infinity), y = -infinity .. infinity));
                           2 Pi
                         - ----
                            l
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `Ib` where you may intend `I*b`.

You have `&Im` where you may intend `Im`.

You place an assumption on `l` but place no helpful assumptions on `a` and `b`. Are both `a` and `b` to be taken as being purely real? I have used such assumptions below.

Below, I utilize `assuming` rather than `assume`, as I find it more convenient and it doesn't tend to lead to a muddle with mixes of distinct instances of both unassumed names and assumed names which ostensibly appear equal.

The syntax you used for assigning `omega` and `Omega` can produce operators (the apparent intention) when used for 2D Math input, albeit via a diambuguation popup. But here we have plaintext source, and such syntax used as 1D Maple Notation code makes remember table assignments instead of operators. Below I use a syntax valid in both 1D and 2D modes for assigning operators to those two names.

The following results each took anywhere from a few seconds to about a minute on 64bit Linux running Maple 17 on an Intel i5.

```
restart;

omega:=(x,y)->1/(1+x^(2)+y^(2))*<2*x,2*y,x^(2)+y^(2)-1>:

Omega:=(x,y,a,b,l)->simplify(omega(evalc(Re((l*(x+I*y)+a+I*b)/
                                            (1-(a-I*b)*(x+I*y)))),
                                   evalc(Im((l*(x+I*y)+a+I*b)/
                                            (1-(a-I*b)*(x+I*y)))))):

T31:=simplify(Int(Int(Omega(x,y,a,b,l)[3]
                      *(diff(Omega(x,y,a,b,l)[1],x)),
                      x=-infinity..infinity),y=-infinity..infinity),
              size) assuming real, l>0:

 simplify(value(subs(b=0,T31))) assuming real, l>0;

                                     2
                              2 Pi (a  + l)
                            - -------------
                                  2    2
                                 a  + l

 simplify(value(T31)) assuming real, l>0;

                4    2  2    4    2  2    2      2      3
            2 (a  + a  l  - b  + b  l  + a  l - b  l + l ) Pi
          - -------------------------------------------------
                4      2  2      2  2    4      2  2    4
               a  + 2 a  b  + 2 a  l  + b  + 2 b  l  + l

 T11:=simplify(Int(Int(Omega(x,y,a,b,l)[1]
                       *(diff(Omega(x,y,a,b,l)[1],x)),
                       x=-infinity..infinity),y=-infinity..infinity),
               size) assuming real, l>0:

 simplify(value(subs(b=0,T11))) assuming real, l>0;

                                   0

 simplify(value(T11)) assuming real, l>0;

                                   0
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks good. But i still don't understand why it is so long to compute the primitive of a rational fraction.

Comment: Using your original code as 1D Maple Notation (even with the operators made working) the integrand generated is not as you've described, on account of the mistakes mentioned in the first two paragraphs of my answer. And by default Maple will treat unknowns `a` and `b` as complex, which likely makes it much harder to compute.